# Outlook rule to move all calendar related items to specific folder

Tags: calendar, outlook, rules

I organize an event and invite attendants. They respond with different options - accepted, rejected, tentative and others - it is up to their local language what is reason of confusion.
I need to create such rule (without API if it is possible) which will gather all calendar items and move them to specific folder.
Now using 'Rules Wizard' we have e.g. 'assigned to category' but it does not meet the expectations for these categories are related to colors used to mark an item; there is also 'which is a meeting invitation or update' but it does not meet the expectations for it is related to events organized by someone else.
I just want to organize all responds for my own events.

Comment: Why not use the "specific words in the subject to a folder" rule? and place text that is always in the return mail as a rule.

Comment: Because such solution requires to build up words collection. At this moment I have following:
Accepted:
Declined:
Zugesagt:
Zaakceptowane:
Meeting Forward Notification:
Automatyczna odpowiedz:
- and if someone will answer from his workstation with foreign language I need to modify rule. Of course only once but maybe there is smarter solution.

Answer (score 2):

This thread popped up after a Google search for the same problem. I found the solution here:
http://www.uvic.ca/systems/support/emailcalendar/facultystaff/outlook2010/filterinvitationresponses.php

In summary:
Go to the "uses form name form" condition and look at the "Application forms".

Comment: The link is dead, but the solution is exactly what I was looking for.